# Vuex store not updating when I make changes

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

In my project, in my src/store/index.js file I have a cloudinary object with a cloud_name property, in my Vuex.store:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  state: {
    user: {},
    signupLayout: false,
    adminLayout: false,
    sidebarOpen: false,
    homeLayout: false, 
    cloudinary: {
      cloud_name: "example",
      base_upload_preset: "*****",
      channel_header_upload_preset: "*****",
      profile_image_upload_preset: "*****",
      audio_upload_preset: "*****",
      cover_image_upload_preset: "*****",
```

When I go to my Vue file and console log cloudinary.cloud_name, everything works as expected

```
example
```

But when I try to change cloud_name to something like ‘example2’ such that the code looks like:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
  state: {
    user: {},
    signupLayout: false,
    adminLayout: false,
    sidebarOpen: false,
    homeLayout: false, 
    cloudinary: {
      cloud_name: "example2", // change cloud_name
      base_upload_preset: "*****",
      channel_header_upload_preset: "*****",
      profile_image_upload_preset: "*****",
      audio_upload_preset: "*****",
      cover_image_upload_preset: "*****",
```

When I try to console log cloudinary.cloud_name, it’s showing the old cloud name instead of the new.

```
example
```

Why is it doing this? Why is the state not changing?

Comment: do you change it in hardcode or with some method ?

Comment: I changed it in hardcode

Comment: You use createPersistedState. If you don't want the state to persist, don't use it.

Comment: I need persistedState, just not for that one thing. But I thought it detected when you made changes to the code?

Comment: No, persisted state stores your vuex information in the browser. Try in an incognito session or in another browser to see the difference. To fix this, you will have to manually remove the data from the browser.

Comment: OK thanks that helped. Is there a way to only have persisted state for specific things?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is that you are not changing the state in the right way. Do you have mutations that are changing your state?

My favorite guide to understanding the update-loop in Vuex is [Adam Jhar's "Vuex Explained Visually"](https://medium.com/vue-mastery/vuex-explained-visually-f17c8c76d6c4) (even though I disagree with making mutation names SHOUTING_SNAKE_CASE). My favorite part is this image:

[image: animated vuex modification loop]

In short:

- Don't directly change your state
- Change the state through a mutation
- Call mutations from Vuex actions, or directly from components

Once you have the right workflow, things like your persisted state plugin may start to work, vue dev tools will be able to watch the mutations and show you helpful things, and your application will update correctly with the state changes.

A lot of people start this off and say "oh that's a lot of extra work" and they're right, but it's important to do it the right way.